# My datasource is holding a value, but EVAL does not display the value in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has a datasource that is an IENUMERABLE.  When I debug and view the results of the datasource, I can see that there is a field that is pulled called strTONumber and it is populated, however when my gridview has a field that uses the EVAL on the field, nothing shows up.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTONumber" Text='TO: <%# Eval("strTONumber") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

every other item that is pulled through the datasource and displayed using the Eval works, except this one field.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTONumber" Text='<%# Eval("strTONumber", "TO: {0}") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

or

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTONumber" Text='<%# "TO: " + Eval("strTONumber") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

or

```
<asp:Label ID="lblToPrefix" Text='TO:' runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblTONumber" Text='<%# Eval("strTONumber") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

or

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTONumber" Text='<%# AddPreFix(Eval("strTONumber"))%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

protected string AddPreFix(object txt)
{
    return "TO:" + txt.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I overlooked that

Comment: Changed my answer since @Doozer and I had the same solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing it to

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTONumber" Text='<%# "TO: " + Eval("strTONumber") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```